# Parallel AJAX calls in Vaadin javascript extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to write a simple Vaadin Extension in javascript (meaning I subclass `AbstractJavaScriptExtension`) that triggers a method call on the server side.  This method call will e.g. load some data and update the UI of the component.  Basically the idea is to have single-shot asynchronous requests for each component with the goal of having the potentially long-running database / webservice calls at the server side run in parallel.

Since I don't need to continuously update the components, using Vaadin Push would be overkill.  I'd like to use plain old XHR.

So I added a javascript trigger function in my extension class like this:

```
addFunction("trigger", jsonArray -> command.trigger());
```

(this is java 8 syntax, `trigger()` is just a method on a Functional Interface)

And I tried simply calling this trigger immediately in my javascript connector like this:

```
window.com_example_AsyncTrigger = function () {
    this.trigger();
}
```

I wrote a dummy component that simulates slow loading using `Thread.sleep()` and created three instances, with 10, 6 and 2 second delays, while logging the start and end timestamps of the loading.
I then extended three layouts with my extension, to add each component into when its corresponding trigger is fired.

And sure, all three triggers are fired, but they are fired within the same request (I could tell from the logging that they were executed in a single server thread).  This means after about 18 seconds, all 3 components are updated at once, while I would expect the 2 second component to be shown first, then the 6 second component, and lastly the 10 second componentt, in a total time of about 10 seconds.

So, I figured out this must be because Vaadin somehow queues the function calls done when creating the connection wrappers and calls the server side methods on a single request.  So I changed my javascript connector implementation to call the client side `trigger()` function asynchronously, like this:

```
window.com_example_AsyncTrigger = function () {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() { self.trigger();}, 0);
}
```

And sure, these triggers now fire in separate requests, as I can tell from the logging that the names of the worker threads are different.
The only problem is... they still run sequentially.  The calls to `self.trigger()` are done in rapid succession, but the actual XHR requests are not done in parallel.  The next one is started only after the previous one completes.

Why is this, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webserver doesn't process requests from the same client in parallel to prevent any race conditions or locking issues. To process long running requests you need to do it asynchronous to the thread that processed the request. When it is finished, write the result back to the UI, using UI.access(...). The Thread that processed the request will return and the next request will be processed. The problem is than that the result won't be send to server till the client sends the next request. But all long running requests are processed in parallel.

First option:

Poll the server regularly (there is a vaadin addon for that). Than the result will be send with the next poll.

Second option:

Instead of polling just use push. The overhead isn't that large, if you don't expect hundreds of users at the same time, it shouldn't be an issue.

Further explanation:

From what I understand about the Vaadin Framework is that it processes requests the following way:

1. process any changes that are send from the client
2. call your Listeners (ValueChange, Click, ...)
3. send changes to the client

When a second thread would change the URL while the first thread is in the thrid step, this could cause serious problem because just half of the changes would be transmitted to the client. Vaadin throws an Exception when it detects that an tells you to use UI.access(...). UI.access() takes care of executing the provided Runnable directly (when no other request is processed) or asynchronously after the currently running request is finished.
One finally note. The lock is session based not just UI based. So changes to different UIs in the same session (e.g. different tabs of the same application) are also processed sequentially.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know about that.  I'm using Tomcat.  I don't find any references about this behaviour (processing async requests from same client sequentially).
Main reason I'd want to stay away from Push is that websockets can cause issues with proxies, load balancers etc. when this code goes to production.  So I'd like to avoid the additional accidental complexity if possible, certainly for something this simple.

Comment: I'd like to accept this answer, but would like a little bit more detail on why the server doesn't process asynchronous requests in parallel.  After all, when I call a REST webservice from my webapp on another Tomcat server, it will be from the same IP even if it's for different users.  But still the webservice handles the requests in parallel (I should hope).  If it works for webservice calls then why not for Ajax calls?  What's the difference?

Comment: I'll assume it's just Vaadin who locks the UI during request processing so that async requests from the same browser window get processed sequentially and accept this answer.

Comment: Added some further explanation how vaadin processed synchronous requests and how to change the UI state from an other thread.

Comment: Btw the option I chose was to write my own `AbstractJavascriptExtension` subclass that polls the server until the data is loaded (similar to `Refresher` which is a `Component`, but I prefer an extension).  I update the UI from the same thread that does the poll request (not the one that loads the data) so it seems locking (`UI.access()`) is not necessary (it would be necessary with Push).